# javascript output [object HTMLCollection]

Tags: javascript, arrays

Since i've got no clue after doing research i got to the point to ask.

So The Following code is supposed to output the inside of the array as divs more precise as a simple block.
For some reason every "B01" will be output as [object HTMLCollection] , instead as a block as defined in css.
So how does that happen and how can I fix it?

```js
var B01 = document.getElementsByClassName("block_matrix");

var level = [B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01,
    B01, B01, B01,B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01, B01 , B01];
    

  document.write(level);
```

```css
body, html{
 margin:0;
 border:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color: grey;
}
#game{
 width:90%;
 height: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;

}

.block_matrix{
 width:5%;
 height:5%;
 background-color:orange;
 z-index:1;
 position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="script/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gfx/style.css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>


<div id="game">
<script>
</script>

</div>

<div class="block_matrix">
</div>



</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you expect that `document.write()` call to do

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var B01 = document.getElementsByClassName("block_matrix")[0];
```

or

```
var B01 = document.getElementsByClassName("block_matrix")[0].outerHTML;
```

This will solve your current problem, but then you will meet another problem because you are using document.write()

Comment: What should I use instead? i think it worked  so far as you mentioned.

Comment: I am not really sure what your intentions are, but right now you replace all of your HTML with levels, it seems like you want to add a lot of block_matrix, but still keep the game, which would be solved like this.

    `for(var i=0;i<level.length;i++){
      var currentLevel = level[i];
      document.body.appendChild(currentLevel);
    }`

But your css is wrong for block

Comment: I think i found what i needed. Thank you first of all.